# Converting detailed Date column into grouped by month column format

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012, grouping

I am attempting to take a column entitled "CREAT_DTTM" from table TEMPSO_INV_DATA which holds "creation date" of an invoice (and associated data) and convert that date format to one that follows the equal sign below, in a new table and title that column MONTH.  Basically grouping all invoices for each month, into their corresponding month in this format "??/1/2014". I am still very new to SQL so this one definitely stumped me, i hope my explanation was not too convoluted.

```
  Creat_Dttm                   Month
2014-01-01 00:33:58.000      = 1/1/2014
2014-01-01 07:40:01.000      = 1/1/2014
2014-01-03 01:50:12.000      = 1/1/2014
2014-02-18 11:42:13.000      = 2/1/2014 
2014-02-20 07:49:11.000      = 2/1/2014
2014-04-09 06:02:36.000      = 4/1/2014
```

Comment: what dbms are you using?

Comment: Sorry.. SQL Server 2012 ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select CAST(MONTH(Creat_Dttm) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/1/' + CAST(YEAR(Creat_Dttm) AS VARCHAR(4)) as month 
from TEMPSO_INV_DATA
```

Comment: Wow.. Thank you very much.. that looked like it did the trick!!